# Plugin layout not applied to partial view on all tabs on tab control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs

I am using a bootstrap.multiselect.js plugin inside a _unitProduct partial view as this partial view will be used on all the tabs on tab control.
plugin gets applied/loaded on first tab once page/first tab is loaded. but its not loaded for other tabs with same partial view, ends up displaying regular 
dropdownlist without any plugin layout applied.

I have included the script file in master layout page and binding using control id **$('#ProductTypeID').multiselect();**

```
  Included in master layout:
  <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


   _unitProduct.cshtml (partial view)
   <div class="span6">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.ProductTypeID, "Product Type", new { @class = "small" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ProductTypeID, new SelectList(productTypes, "Key", "Value"))
        </div>
    </div>

   Product.cshtml (main view)
   <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
              @{ Html.RenderPartial("_unitProduct", Model.ProductA);}
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane primary" id="tab2">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_unitProduct", Model.ProductB);}
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane primary" id="tab3">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_unitProduct", Model.ProductC);}
         </div>
   </div>

  JavaScript
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#ProductTypeID').multiselect();
   });



 Rendered HTML
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Page3</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
     maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-    
    awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container fixed">

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="box-generic">
            <div class="tabsbar">
                <div class="widget-head">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1-2" class="glyphicons" data-toggle="tab"><span>OccupantA</span></a></li>
                        <li class="primary"><a href="#tab2-2" class="glyphicons" data-toggle="tab"><span>OccupantB</span></a></li>
                        <li class="primary"><a href="#tab3-2" class="glyphicons" data-toggle="tab"><span>Occupant C</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">

            <!-- Step 1 -->
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1-2">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="innerwell">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                                <label class="small" for="PersonTypeID">Person Type</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select id="PersonTypeID" name="PersonTypeID" style="display: none;">
                                        <option value="-">--</option>
                                        <option value="D">D-Driver</option>
                                        <option value="O">O-Occupant</option>
                                        <option value="P">P-Pedestrian</option>
                                    </select><div class="btn-group" style="width: 52px;">
                                        <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-custom" data-toggle="dropdown" title="--" style="width: 52px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span class="multiselect-selected-text">-</span> <b class=""></b></button>
                                        <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                                            <li class="active"><a tabindex="0">
                                                <label class="radio">
                                                    <input type="radio" value="-">
                                                    --</label></a></li>
                                            <li><a tabindex="0">
                                                <label class="radio">
                                                    <input type="radio" value="D">
                                                    D-Driver</label></a></li>
                                            <li><a tabindex="0">
                                                <label class="radio">
                                                    <input type="radio" value="O">
                                                    O-Occupant</label></a></li>
                                            <li><a tabindex="0">
                                                <label class="radio">
                                                    <input type="radio" value="P">
                                                    P-Pedestrian</label></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            BindMultiselect();
                        });

                        function BindMultiselect() {
                            $('#PersonTypeID').multiselect();
                        }
                    </script>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Step 2 -->
            <div class="tab-pane primary" id="tab2-2">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="innerwell">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                                <label class="small" for="PersonTypeID">Person Type</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select id="PersonTypeID" name="PersonTypeID">
                                        <option value="-">--</option>
                                        <option value="D">D-Driver</option>
                                        <option value="O">O-Occupant</option>
                                        <option value="P">P-Pedestrian</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            BindMultiselect();
                        });

                        function BindMultiselect() {

                            $('#PersonTypeID').multiselect();
                        }

                    </script>

                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <!-- Step 3 -->
            <div class="tab-pane primary" id="tab3-2">
                <div class="innerwell">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                            <label class="small" for="PersonTypeID">Person Type</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select id="PersonTypeID" name="PersonTypeID">
                                    <option value="-">--</option>
                                    <option value="D">D-Driver</option>
                                    <option value="O">O-Occupant</option>
                                    <option value="P">P-Pedestrian</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        BindMultiselect();
                    });

                    function BindMultiselect() {
                        $('#PersonTypeID').multiselect();
                    }

                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindMultiselect();
    });

    function BindMultiselect() {
        $('#PersonTypeID').multiselect();
    }
</script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidh can u share some code sample

Comment: once rendered jquery applies plugin layout to first control id (productTypeId) and leave rest of the controls with same id.

Comment: last one thing.. .
Share generated HTML as well ..

Comment: check out the rendered html.